# Swift return value from function inside dispatch group notify

Tags: swift

I am trying to return a value from a function after executing a function that is not finishing immediately.

for example:

```
func returnSomeValue() -> String {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    service.longTimeTofinish(onFinish: { group.leave() } ) // <-- this function takes long time to finish

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        return "Returning some value as example" // <-- Here is the issue
    }
}
```

The compiler is showing an error "Cannot convert value of type 'String' to closure result type Void". The closure inside notify can't return value to my outer function. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Don't `return` as such, you are using an async call, why do you want to make it sync? Usually, that's bad idea. Are you sure about that? WHy not do `func yourFunc(completion: ((String) -> Void))` instead? What's the code calling for `returnSomeValue()`?

Comment: Technically, I think you can `group.wait()` rather than `group.notify`, but I don't think that is something you should do.

Comment: You are misusing `DispatchGroup`. It’s not designed for making **one** asynchronous task synchronous.

Comment: I had the same question regarding the `DispatchGroup.notify()`. This thread answers my question, whereas the referenced one does not. I don't think this is a duplicate and should be reopened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Return inside the `notify` is `void` it's scope is different than the function , You need a completion

```
func returnSomeValue(completion:@escaping((String) -> ())) {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    service.longTimeTofinish(onFinish: { group.leave() } ) // <-- this function takes long time to finish

    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion("Returning some value as example")
    }
}
```

Or what is more common

```
func returnSomeValue(completion:@escaping((String) ->())) { 
    service.longTimeTofinish(onFinish: { completion("Returning some value as example") } )  
}
```